# Show that there is a is a non-trivial homomorphism $f: \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ if and only if $\gcd(n,m) \neq 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Show that there is a is a non-trivial homomorphism $f: \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ if and only if $\gcd(n,m) \neq 1$.

By Lagrange's theorem order of element in a group $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$  has to divide $n$ and order of element of group $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ has to divide $m$ but if $\gcd(n,m) = 1$ group structure is not preserved by homomorphism. Is that right?

Comment: Hint: If $\phi$ is a group homomorphism, $o(\phi(g))\mid o(g)$. I'm not sure what you mean by "group structure is not preserved by homomorphism." By definition, a homomorphism in some sense preserves the group structure. What makes $\phi$ a homomorphism by definition is the fact that $\phi(g\cdot h) = \phi(g)\cdot \phi(h)$ Also, to say $\phi$ is "non-trivial" means that $\phi$ is not identically equal to $e$, the identity element.

Comment: Also, one part of this is true in general : If $(|G|, |H|) = 1$, then there is no non-trivial homomorphism from $G$ to $H$. The argument is identical.

Answer (score 1):

$\Rightarrow$ : If $(n,m)=1$ and if $f: {\bf Z}_n\rightarrow {\bf Z}_m$ is a nontrivial, i.e., $f(1)=a\neq 0$, then $$0=f(n)=na,\ m|na $$

Hence we have $m|a$. This is a contradiction.

$\Leftarrow $ : If $(n,m)=d > 1$ and if all homomorphisms 
$f: {\bf Z}_n\rightarrow {\bf Z}_m$ are trivial, then consider $$f(1)=m/d.$$

Hence we have a nontrivial homomorphism. Contradiction.